Differences in Record Count Due to Intermediate Table Usage in Hive HQL JOIN Queries
Problem
I am investigating the cause of a difference in the record count when performing a JOIN operation in Hive HQL between Table1, Table2, and subsequently Table3 using two different methods described below.
I would like to seek your advice on the cause and possible solutions for this issue.
Environment

This phenomenon occurs in an environment where the software version has been updated as part of a system renewal. This issue did not occur in the pre-renewal environment, where the record count after the JOIN operation did not decrease.
The environmental conditions under which the phenomenon occurs are described below.

The Two Methods Compared

The two methods are as follows. The difference is whether the intermediate result is stored in a table or not.
The Hql_A method produces the expected record count, but Hql_B results in a significantly lower record count than expected.

Hql_A

Save the result of the JOIN between Table1 and Table2 into a table, then JOIN this table with Table3.

Hql_B

Assign an alias to the result of the JOIN between Table1 and Table2, then directly JOIN this result with Table3.

The approximate record counts for each table and the expected result are as follows.
Record Counts of Each Table



Table name
Num of Records




Table1
75,000,000


Table2
150,000,000


Table3
75,000,000



Expected Result
74,000,000
Actual Results



HQL
Num of Records
Note




Hql_1
74,000,000
As expected


Hql_2
4,000,000
Much lower




The environment where the issue was confirmed is as follows:



Software
Version




Hadoop
3.3.3 (Apache Hadoop)


Hive
3.1.3 (Apache Hive)


Architecture
x86_64


hive execution engine
mr



Additionally, there exists an environment where the issue does not occur (Hql_B produces the expected result).
The details of that environment are described later.
Table Structure
Table1

Number of Records

75,000,000


Column Structure

id



Table2

Number of Records

150,000,000


Column Structure

id



Table3

Number of Records

75,000,000


Column Structure

id



JOIN Conditions
JOIN between Table1 and Table2

ON Condition

Table1.id = Table2.id


Expected Result after JOIN (Num of Records)

74,000,000 Records



JOIN between "JOIN result of Table1 and Table2" and Table3

ON Condition

JOIN_result.id = Table3.id


Expected Result after JOIN (Num of Records)

74,000,000 Records



Specific HQL for Each Method
Hql_A
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM (SELECT table1.id
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
) subquery
JOIN table3 ON subquery.id = table3.id;

Hql_B
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE temp_table
  SELECT table1.id, table1.code
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id;
 
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM temp_table
JOIN table3 ON temp_table.id = table3.id;

Issue Occurrence Based on Different Environments and Software Versions
In the following environment, the expected result (record count) is achieved with Hql_B as well.
Environment Where the Issue Did Not Occur (On-premises)



Software
Version




Hadoop
0.20.0 (CDH3u6)


Hive
0.7.1 (CDH3u6)


Architecture
x86_64


hive execution engine
mr



Environment Where the Issue Did Not Occur (AWS EMR Serverless)



Software
Version




Release Version
emr-6.7.0


Hive
3.1.3 (Apache Hive)


Architecture
amr64


hive execution engine
TeZ



Environment Where the Issue Occurred (Reposted)



Software
Version




Hadoop
3.3.3 (Apache Hadoop)


Hive
3.1.3 (Apache Hive)


Architecture
x86_64


hive execution engine
mr



I would greatly appreciate any advice or suggestions.
